# Nestjs, Where to handle relation between ressources in a restApi

Tags: javascript, rest, architecture, nestjs

In a **nestjs restful api** using **mongoose**, what is the common (and good) way to handle the relation between ressources.
My project follow almost [this structure](https://github.com/mguay22/nestjs-mongo/tree/unit-testing/src), the only difference is i use repository instead of entity.

Taking the example with a `Cat` repository (from the [nestjs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#routing)), i can have another `Food` repository. This is not exclusif to the cat, it contains all kinds of food, but contains some Cat food too.

If i want to **get the food related to my** `type` **of Cat**, taking the restful api requirement, my endpoint will be:

```
/cat/:type/foods
```

> This seems pretty clear and i like it.

Now, in my real app i have the following structure:
[image]

Like you can see, each ressources have a link with the oher at one moment. So, what the path need to be for each ressources when i for exemple get one by ID or when i get it with the relation?

---

Resources use:

https://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction/
[image: relation for orders]

https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinon, because it's a many-to-many relationship. you should follow the offical JSONAPI documentation: https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#urls-relationships

In case you want to find a Cat's food (1 to many), you should use the following url schema:

```
/cats/:type/relationship/food
```

In case you want to find the cats that relate to a specific food (1 to many), you should use the following url schema:

```
/food/:type/relationship/cats
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So based on what i see about the article rest-introduction. We don't follow the restApi requirement, am i wrong?

Comment: This is the best doc i would use, but it's up to you to decide:
https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/

Comment: thanks i take time to read it and do more research.
I updated my question, because i still don't know how can i do it, because creating controller for each relation seems pretty big and weird for me.

Comment: updated my answer, please look on it